# I can't install Angular CLI properly

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I have been searching for solutions, but I still can't install Angular CLI on my computer. I always get errors. What seems to be the problem? Help.

I already tried running the cmd line as an administrator, but it still does not work. I also tried clearing the npm cache.

My node.js is in the latest version: Node.js v15.5.1.

This is the console log error:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! dest C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@angular\.cli-gTnE0exE
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@angular\.cli-gTnE0exE'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\@angular\.cli-gTnE0exE'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\@angular\\.cli-gTnE0exE'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Try reducing your node version. Try something like node 12

Comment: @emmanelagarry I tried reducing my node version. It solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following; If you are on windows try to run below command using admin access and on linux based systems use sudo:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

These commands will actually remove the previous installations and then check:

```
ng --version --> it should throw an error
```

Reinstall the angular package:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then check your version again:

```
ng --version
```

To add one more thing, you can use multiple versions of node. So if you are using linux based computer. You can install nvm and you can install multiple versions of node: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm -- and for windows, you can use this : https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

This way you can check what versions of node are causing an issue, or it is actually a problem with angular installation.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, it turns out the latest version was causing an issue